# New install of cygwin requires manual login on each restart

Tags: bash, cygwin

I've recently had to reinstall Cygwin on to a new drive, and I tried to copy my .bash_profile over as well. But for some reason I can't use any of my old aliases in Cygwin unless I use "bash --login" first.

I never had to do this on my old install, did I do something wrong setting it up this time? Alternately, is there just a way to make it run this command automatically on each startup, without having to use Cygwin.bat (As I prefer the mintty terminal)?

Comment: Are you starting the cygwin terminal via a shortcut? if so, what is the complete target? in particular, does it end with `-` to indicate that mintty should start a login shell?

Comment: I'm just running mintty.exe

Comment: ... so if you run `mintty.exe -` do you get the desired behavior?

Comment: Oh, sorry yeah that worked. Thanks.